# Utalization of classes in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to teach myself about OOP in python and am really struggling.

I have the following:

```
        def __init__(self, quantity):
            ''' '''
            self.switchboard = []
            self.state = False
            self.quantity = quantity
            for i in range(quantity):
                self.switchboard.append(i)

        def __str__(self):
            self.on_list = []
            for i in range(self.quantity):
                if i == True:
                    self.on_list.append(i)
            return("The following switches are on " + str(self.on_list))
        def which_switch(self):
            for i in range(len(self.switchboard)):
                self.on_list = []
                if self.switchboard[i] == True:
                    on_list.append(i)
                print(on_list)

        def flip(self, n):
            if self.switchboard[n] == True:
                self.switchboard[n] = False
            else:
                self.switchboard[n] = True
```

When I print it, I get `The following switches are on [1]`. Even though I put `10` in the parameters. I want it to display all the switches that are on which in this case should be zero since their initial state is 'off'.

Comment: Can you provide the code that calls `LightSwitch`.

Comment: Nice example, I even learned something while pythonizing some of your methods :o)

Answer (score 1):

In `__str__` modify the line:

```
if i == True:
```

to:

```
if self.switchboard[i]:
```

Remember: `i` is just an index, what you want is to access the i-th item in switchboard!

There is also another bug, in method `which_switch()`:

```
on_list.append(i)
```

should be:

```
self.on_list.append(i)
```

and same goes to the print line below it.

Output after the change:

```
The following switches are on [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now, I can only guess that what you actually wanted to do in the constructor is:

```
def __init__(self, quantity):
    ''' '''
    self.switchboard = []
    self.state = False
    self.quantity = quantity
    for i in range(quantity):
        self.switchboard.append(LightSwitch('off'))  # create light-switch and set it to 'off'
```

and then, when you print them - print only the ones that are on:

```
def __str__(self):
    self.on_list = []
    for i in range(self.quantity):
        if self.switchboard[i].state: # check state
            self.on_list.append(i)
    return("The following switches are on " + str(self.on_list))
```

Comment: @jason39481 now you're asking a different question... I don't see where do you turn them off: in the `__init__` you're setting: `self.state = False` which refers to the whole `switchboard` - not to any specific switch.

Answer (score 0):

Also the reason it's printing 1 as true, is because out of all the elements in list, it's just seeing everything as false and 1 as true (as in 0 == False, 1 == True).

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten

```
def flip(self):
    ''' Sets switch to opposite position.'''
    if self.state == True:
        self.state = False

    elif self.state == False:
        self.state = True
```

to

```
def flip(self):  
    ''' Sets switch to opposite position.'''
    self.state = not self.state
```

and on your switchboard for

```
    def flip_every(self, n):
        for i in range(0, len(self.switchboard), n):
            if self.switchboard[n] == True:
                self.switchboard[n] = False
            else:
                self.switchboard[n] = True
```

to

```
def flip_every(self, n):
    for i in range(0, self.quantity, n):
        self.switchboard[n] = not self.switchboard[n]
        # you could also just use self.flip(n) instead
```

and

```
def flip(self, n): 
    self.switchboard[n] =  not self.switchboard[n]
```

As a nice touch: you use kind-of the same iteration in `which_switch(self)` and  `__str__(self):` that operates on the indexes of switches that are `on`. I built a small `def getOnIndexes(self): ...` that returns you an int list of those indexes, and call this in both methods (DRY - dont repeat yourself principle) using a shorthand to create indexes based on a list comprehension.

```
    def getOnIndexes(self):
        return [i for i in range(self.quantity) if self.switchboard[i] == True]
```

In total a really nice small OOP example.

What had me stumped though, is why a Switchboard IS_A LightSwitch - I would model it slightly different, saying a SwitchBoard HAS LightSwitch'es, coming to this:

*Your base class*

```
class LightSwitch(): 
    def __init__(self, default_state):
        '''  
        default_state can only be 'on' or 'off'.
        '''
        if default_state == 'on':
            self.state = True
        elif default_state == 'off':
            self.state = False

    def turn_on(self): 
        self.state = True

    def turn_off(self): 
        self.state = False

    def flip(self): 
        self.state = not self.state 

    def __str__(self): 
        if self.state == True:
            return 'I am on'

        if self.state == False:
            return 'I am off'

    def isOn(self):
        return self.state

    def isOff(self):
        return not self.isOn()
```

My alternative switch board:

```
class AlternateSwitchBoard():
    ''' ''' 
    def __init__(self, quantity, default_state):
        ''' '''
        self.default_state = default_state
        self.switchboard = [LightSwitch(default_state) for x in range(quantity)]
        self.state = False
        self.quantity = quantity


    def __str__(self):
        retVal = ""
        for i in range(self.quantity):
            if self.switchboard[i].isOn():
                retVal += ", On"
            else:   
                retVal += ", Off"
        return "Switchboard: " + retVal[1:].strip() 

    def which_switch(self):
        print(self.getOnIndexes())

    def flip(self, n):
        self.switchboard[n].flip() 

    def flip_every(self,stride):
        for i in range(0, self.quantity, stride):
            self.switchboard[i].flip()

    def reset(self):
        self.switchboard = [LightSwitch(default_state) for x in range(quantity)]

    def getOnIndexes(self):
        return [i for i in range(self.quantity) if self.switchboard[i].isOn()]  

s2 = AlternateSwitchBoard(10, "off")
s2.flip(2)
s2.flip(7) 
print(str(s2))
s2.flip_every(2) 
print(str(s2))
s2.which_switch()
```

Output:

```
Switchboard: Off, Off, On, Off, Off, Off, Off, On, Off, Off
Switchboard: On, Off, Off, Off, On, Off, On, On, On, Off
[0, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Comparison, not assignement.

Comment: I think you mean `self.state = not self.state`.

Comment: nice: `self.state = not self.state`  == `self.state ^= self.state`